# How do I download and save multiple files from google drive to a particular folder on my laptop using R and googledrive package

Tags: r, purrr

I'm following the instructions in [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-download-a-google-drives-contents-based-on-drive-id-or-url/16896/12) post to download 2 csv files from my google drive to my computer. Here is the code provided -

```
library(googledrive)
library(purrr)

## store the URL you have
folder_url <- "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7tJg2i5HAo2c0VzVFVhLUdQcnM"

## identify this folder on Drive
## let googledrive know this is a file ID or URL, as opposed to file name
folder <- drive_get(as_id(folder_url))

## identify the csv files in that folder
csv_files <- drive_ls(folder, type = "csv")

## download them
walk(csv_files$id, ~ drive_download(as_id(.x)))
```

The instructions above download the csv files to my "documents" folder. I am trying to download the files to a particular folder on my laptop using a slight modification to the last bit of code

```
walk(csv_files$id, ~ drive_download(as_id(.x),
                                    path = "../Desktop/data_folder/,
                                    overwrite = TRUE))
```

Unfortunately, this is saving a single .xlsx file which does not contain any data and cannot be opened. How do I correct the code to save both files to a particular folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `path` parameter wants a full filename, not just a path to a directory. So by default it figures out the filename using goodledrive methods and uses it to create a file on your computer in your current working directory. But if you don't want this default behavior you should also provide the file name. So essentially there are two options:

1. Set your working directory to the folder you want your files to be downloaded to before running the code you provided. (and then most likely it'll be a good idea to change it back)
2. Rewrite the script so that `path` parameter is built using the googledrive filename. Something like this:

```r
path <- "~/Documents/tmp/data_folder/"
for (i in seq_along(csv_files$name)) {
  drive_download(
    as_id(csv_files$id[[i]]),
    path = file.path(path, csv_files$name[[i]]),
    overwrite = TRUE
  )
}
```

Or if you prefer to use `walk`:

```r
csv_files %>% 
  split(csv_files$id) %>% 
  walk(~drive_download(.$id, path = file.path(path, .$name), overwrite = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only files and no subdirectory, using `purrr`, you could do:

```r
folder <- drive_get(folder_url)

# find files in folder on GD
files = drive_ls(folder)
files_bind <- bind_rows(files). # make it a tibble

# Batch download the files
map2(files_bind$id, files_bind$name, ~drive_download(as_id(.x), path = file.path(dir_local, .y)))
```

Where `dir_local` is the local directory on your machine